# Modular android application - hide sub-APKs in Google Play

Tags: android, modularity

My idea is to have one core application with a list of modules. Modules will be sub-APKs, downloaded from Google Play. User selects a module and proper application will be run (using intent) or downloaded from Google Play (and then run).

Is it possible to hide sub-APKs in Google Play, but still allow to download them directly? There will be about 200 modules and I want to have rating on core app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible to hide something and still have it downloadable.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "hide" - at least in the past, it was possible to upload an application but not list it, such that it could be accessed by those with the specific URL, but would not show up in searches.  However that may no longer be true.